# Define a canonical homomorphism from G/G' to H/H' where K' is the commutator of K.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let  $f: G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Define a canonical homomorphism 
$g: G/G' \to H/H'$ where K' is the commutator of K.

Here's what I did:

Let $a$ be an element of $G/G'$, then $a$ is of the form $xG'$ where $x \in G$. Then I shall define $g: G/G' \to H/H'$ that way: $g(xG')=f(x)H'\in H/H'$. Is that admissible?

Comment: I don't think that is admissible since the representatives may not "combine" adequately

Comment: Any ideas or hints for a proper solutions?

Comment: It is admissible, but you have to prove that $g$ is well-defined. That is, you must show that if $xG'=yG'$ then $g(xG') = g(yG')$. You also have to prove that $g$ is a homomorphism, but that is easy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $f: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism. Consider the canonical homomorphism $\pi :H \to H/H'.$ Let $\phi : G \xrightarrow{f}H \xrightarrow{\pi} H/H'$ be the combined group homomorphism. Show that every for $a, b \in G, \phi ([a, b])$ is the identity element of $H/H'$ where $[a, b] := aba^{-1}b^{-1}.$